# preventing r-value references in variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

looking at [std::ref and std::cref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref), the way I think it works is having two prototypes

```
template< class T >
std::reference_wrapper<const T> cref( const T& t ) noexcept;
template< class T >
void cref( const T&& ) = delete;
```

and the `T&&` template function is deleted.

But when I imitate this with a similar variadic template function, the compilation is successful if atleast one argument satisfies the condition. So now I don't understand how or why this (does not?) works.

```
template<typename ... Ts>
void foo(const Ts& ... ts) { }

template<typename ... Ts>
void foo(const Ts&& ...) = delete;

int main(){
    std::string a{"sss"};
    foo<std::string>(a);
    //foo<std::string>("sss"); error, deleted foo

    foo<std::string, std::string>(a, "sss"); // I was expecting error here
    //foo<std::string, std::string>("aaaa", "sss"); error, deleted foo

    foo<std::string, std::string, std::string>(a, "aaa", "sss"); // I was expecting error here
}
```

This seems to be the case with clang, gcc and also msvc https://godbolt.org/z/8cboT48En

Comment: The 1st overload is taking reference to `const`, which could bind to rvalues too. Note that `std::ref`'s 1st overload is taking reference to non-const.

Comment: Another note to be aware of is that `T&&` is not an rvalue-reference, it's a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). (in the context of deduced template parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinary string literals are lvalues, so your test isn't testing what you want.
Testing with literals that are rvalues, I found you need to have each variant of cv-ref qualifiers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>
#include<string>

template<typename ... Ts>
void foo(const Ts& ... ts) { }

template<typename ... Ts>
void foo(Ts& ... ts) { foo(std::as_const(ts)...); }

template<typename ... Ts>
void foo(const Ts&& ...) = delete;

template<typename ... Ts>
void foo(Ts&& ...) = delete;

using namespace std::string_literals;

int main(){
    std::string a{"sss"};
    foo(a);

    // errors, as desired
    // foo("sss"s); 
    // foo(a, "sss"s);
    // foo("aaaa"s, "sss"s);
    // foo(a, "aaa"s, "sss"s);
}
```

[See it live](https://godbolt.org/z/abGMGYqaG)

Answer (score 0):

You can check std::is_lvalue_reference for this purpose.

```
template<typename ... Ts, std::enable_if_t<(!std::is_lvalue_reference<Ts>::value && ...), int> = 0>
void foo(const Ts& ... ts) {}
```

Then all of calling function like this is error.

```
foo<std::string>("sss"); //error, deleted foo

foo<std::string, std::string>(a, "sss"); // I was expecting error here
foo<std::string, std::string>("aaaa", "sss"); error, deleted foo

foo<std::string, std::string, std::string>(a, "aaa", "sss"); // I was expecting error here
```

Comment: Interestingly this is an error only on gcc, clang and msvc dont show an error.
https://godbolt.org/z/jTd9xbTWz

Comment: @tejas Oh interesting, I just tested with gcc but not clang.

Answer (score 0):

> So now I don't understand how or why this (does not?) works.

Contrary to reference wrapper code, your overload takes reference to **const**:
temporaries can bind to.

If you remove the `const`, you have expected error:

```
template<typename ... Ts> void foo(Ts& ... ts) { /*..*/ }
template<typename ... Ts> void foo(const Ts&& ...) = delete;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eq6jTnb3s)

Comment: @songyuanyao @Jarod42 
There is also std::cref that takes in `const T&`.